# Do i have to create new provisioning profile when submitting new app version to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

So, i have to release a new version for an iOS app that's currently in the app store, and i ask if i have to create a new provisioning profile for distribution  or just use the old profile.
(sorry if this question is so stupid but i spent more than 2 hours searching in google and no response found)

Comment: No, you don't want to create new provisioning profile if you are going to update the existing app with new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no need to create new provision profile when you just update your existing app on app store. But make sure your previously provision profile working correctly with distribution environment.
Hope this help you...

Comment: thanks @Maddyヅヅ , but i still have another question, i notice that the current provision profile will expire in 4 months, is it good to create new provision profile? or let it until expired and regenerate another profile?

Comment: As of now as it's remain 4 month so there is no need to create new one. Once it's expire you need to create new one

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:
- You need 1 certificate for distribution of all apps.
- You need 1 profile for all versions of a single app, if you have 5 apps then you need to create 5 profiles(1 certificate will work for all)

So the answer is **NO**.

regards,
Riyaz

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, No. Just an update on Riyaz's answer.

Even for multiple apps belonging to your company OR your app versions, you don't need to create multiple profiles. This can be achieved by wildcard profiles and we do this all the time.

1. Add a wildcard identifier in identifiers section like: com.MyCompanyName.*
2. Add a profile linked to this wildcard identifier with a valid certificate

You can use this for apps with identifiers matching the wildcard, like com.MyCompanyName.NewApp.